# Parsing XML in AppleScript

Tags: xml, applescript, evernote

I'm trying to parse the tags in an EverNote .enex file (it's just XML), using AppleScript. Here's a snippet from the file I want to parse:

```
<note>
...
<tag>Foo</tag>
<tag>Bar</tag>
...
</note>
```

And here's the AppleScript code that I have (where theNote is a reference to the current <note> in the XML tree which I'm iterating through):

```
set theTags to (value of XML element named "tag" of theNote) as string
```

I'd like theTags to be a list: (Foo, Bar). Hopefully there's a simple way to do this, and I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this;

```
set theTags to value of every XML element of theNote whose name = "tag"
```